# Vectorization of cell-array element manipulation

Tags: octave, vectorization, cell-array

I have a 1xN dimensional cell-array containing matrices of dimension AxB, where A > 0 and B > 2. I want to extract the second and third column of each matrix and create a new cell-array containing these new matrices.

I know I can do this:

```
newcell = cell(size(oldcell));
for i = 1:size(oldcell,2)
    newcell{i} = oldcell{i}(:, [2, 3]);
endfor
```

But I'm wondering if the loop can be avoided by further vectorization?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This can be done with cellfun(), with the option UniformOutput set to false (the default is true).

```
newcell = cellfun(@(x) x(:, [2, 3]), oldcell, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

The reason this doesn't work with UniformOutput=true is that cellfun() then expects the outputs to be scalar, which they are not in this case.